# Google Earth Engine MultiPoint Object Export

Tags: google-earth-engine, point, export

I am using GEE and I have a multipoint object that is all my different sites. I want to be able to export this so I can easily add these points into other scripts and pull up all my sites. I created this multipoint object just by manually selecting them using the "add a marker" feature on the upper left of the map screen. Any tips?

I have tried this with no success:

```
 exports.Potential_DTLB = Potential_DTLB;
```

and also have tried this...

```js
 var sites = ee.FeatureCollection([
  Potential_DTLB]);
  
  Map.addLayer(sites, {}, 'Sites');
  
  Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: sites,
    description: 'ExportCSV',
    fileFormat: 'CSV'});
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "no success"? The first code block you posted should work if you then used `require` to import that from another script. The second code block should export to Drive, although if you're trying to access these from an EE script you'd be better off exporting to asset instead.

Comment: Hi @AaronZuspan, thanks so much for your response. When I try to import it to a new code using require nothing happens, my import code is:  var imports = require('users/.../...:HeliSites');
      print(imports.Potential_DTLB, 'Sites');
       Map.addLayer(imports, {}, 'Sites');

With the second code where im exporting it to drive also nothing happens. I don't receive errors, but it also doesn't export.

Comment: That looks about right, except that you should use `Map.addLayer(imports.Potential_DTLB, {}, 'Sites')` instead of `Map.addLayer(imports, {}, 'Sites')`. When you run `print(imports.Potential_DTLB, 'Sites')`, what shows up in the console? With the Drive export, does a task show up in the `Tasks` tab (top right corner)?

Comment: Thank you, I made that change. Nothing shows up in the console for print(imports.Potential_DTLB, 'Sites'); and a layer is mapped from the following line of code either. with the output to the drive, unfortunately nothing shows up in the tasks either @AaronZuspan

Comment: Just to be sure, you are running the script with the "Run" button or by using "CTRL + Enter", right? Even if there was a bug in the code, you should have *something* show up in the console whenever you use print. If you're running the script and nothing is happening at all, that sounds like it might be a browser issue preventing the page from working correctly. The other possibility would be that there's something else in your script that's freezing the browser like an infinite loop, but that would be noticeable because the tab would crash.

Comment: @AaronZuspan. Yeah im hitting the Run button. Its working now, not really sure what this issue was. Thanks for the help!